# Vector Calculus and the Navier Stokes Equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

I am reading through a paper that derives the thin-film equation from the Navier Stokes equation; however, am having some trouble understanding the vector calculus notation used. For example, the material derivative is defined as:
$$ \frac{D\mathbf{v}}{dt} = \frac{\partial\mathbf{v}}{\partial t}+\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{v}$$
where in $2D$ we have $\mathbf{v}=(u,w)$ and $\nabla=(\partial_x,\partial_z)$. Hence, the gradient of $\mathbf{v}$ is the transpose of the Jacobian given by:
$$ \nabla\mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix} u_x & w_x \\ u_z & w_z \end{bmatrix} $$
Now my question is what to make of:
$$ \mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix} u \\ w \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} u_x & w_x \\ u_z & w_z \end{bmatrix} $$
As far as I am aware the dot product can be defined for two vectors and can be extended to two square matrices but I don't quite know what to make of this when you have a vector and a square matrix.

Specifically, for this case I already know from past experience that:
$$ \frac{D\mathbf{v}}{dt} = \frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial t}+\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla\mathbf{v} = (u_t+uu_x+wu_z,w_t+uw_x+ww_z) $$
but upon coming back to this I am a little confused as to how to show this given the notation above.

Comment: Can you cite the paper?

Comment: This comes from "Modelling of Dynamical Effects Related to the Wettability and Capillarity of Simple and Complex Fluids" by Todorova. But I have seen this in multiple papers that use the NS equations to derive the thin-film equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to write $(\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{v}.$ That makes it clearer:
$$
(\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{v}
= (u \partial_x + w \partial_y) \begin{bmatrix}u\\w\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}(u \partial_x + w \partial_y)u\\(u \partial_x + w \partial_y)w\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: That makes much more sense to me. So is it what I wrote wrong then?

Comment: The question is about the missing time derivative.

Comment: oh yeah sorry that was a typo I will correct that now. My confusion was about this part of the material derivative so I must've just subconsciously skipped over that.

Comment: @Mjoseph. The matrix you had can perhaps be written $\nabla\otimes\mathbf{v}.$

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to parse this, in my opinion, is $(\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{v}$, which sidesteps the matrix issue. However, $\nabla \mathbf{v}$ gets used as a tensor a lot in fluid dynamics, so we should probably still address that. In that case, you should see the dot product as symbolizing [tensor contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction), which generalizes the dot product to tensors of higher rank. In particular, it also includes standard matrix multiplication as the special case for rank 2 tensors.

Whenever I get confused by exactly how expressions with $\nabla$ and dot products shake out, it can be useful to rely on [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), which keeps track of the dot products without having to worry about noncommutativity of tensor contractions.